# asp:RegularExpressionValidator disable button

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, webforms

I have a problem with asp:RegularExpressionValidator when it triggers. it will disable asp.net button even if the user fix the email and it will not make it valid the form?

```
<dd class="lblDemo ddDemo">
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="txtbxIDValidator" runat="server" OnServerValidate="txtbxNameAndId_Validate" Display="Dynamic"
        ForeColor="Red"></asp:CustomValidator>
</dd>
<dd class="lblDemo ddDemo">
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="txtbxEmailRequiredValidator" runat="server" OnServerValidate="txtbxEmailRequired_Validate"
        Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtEmailFormatValidator" ErrorMessage="Please give a valid Email Address" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtbxEmail" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
        ForeColor="red" Display="Dynamic" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="txtbxEmailDomainValidator" runat="server" OnServerValidate="txtbxEmailDomain_Validate"
        Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CustomValidator>
</dd>
</dl>
<p style="text-align: center">
    <%--<asp:Button ID="btnPrevious1" class="btnDemoNext" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnPrevious_Click" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true" Visible="False" />--%>
    <asp:Button ID="btnNext2" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" class="btnDemoNext" OnClick="btnNext_Click"
        OnClientClick="this.disabled=true" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove below code from button definition.

```
OnClientClick="this.disabled=true"
```

You can add validationgroup with button and regularexpression validator. To know more how to use validationgroup you can follow the articles below
[Validation Group In Asp.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)
[Validation Group in Asp.Net](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/use-of-validation-group-in-asp-net1)